# Car wheels goes off place and all this chaos happens when rigged

Tags: rigging

I named the body without joining it but parenting to empty.

Parented each tire without calipers to empty.

Tried selecting everything and adding armature & also only selecting empties, but still it has same problem.

Even after fixing each bone separately, it still generates the wrong rig.

[Here](https://imgur.com/a/b0BjALZ) is the rig before generating it.

[image]